# Excel prepends extra line (but not carriage return) in mult-line cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

Sometimes I use `ALT` + `ENTER` to make multi-line cells.

However, Excel often appears to prepend an extra line for some reason, even though it's not an actual carriage return.  Usually, you can adjust the size of the cell and make the apparent extra line go away.  Sometimes you can't, or it requires adjusting things that don't make sense.

How can I get rid of the visible extra line at the beginning of a cell when it's not a carriage return from something like `ALT` + `ENTER`?

I've been dealing with this for many years through many versions of excel, so I don't think a specific version is warranted in the tag.

### The usual work around

Usually, you can autoadjust the size of the column and then autosize the row and that takes care of it.  Sometimes you have to make the column much more wider than the contents of the cell, autosize the row, and then can autosize the column.

### Artificial Example Screenshots

This is an artificial example, but happens to show the white space I am referring to, albeit much more than I get when there's a problem.  I made this by typing the lines, at which point Excel made it a very tall cell.  I autosized the column on the X axis, and this is what was left.  Similar but different to what I do when I encounter the problem.  Since the problem is not very repeatable, there's no way for me to force a natural screenshot.

[image]

This is what it looks like after I auto size the row:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some screen caps showing this behaviour?

Comment: Have you ever tried Backspace!! What I did,, entered word pressed ALT+Enter then One more word,, ALt+Enter few times,, and used Backspace, Excel then removes white spaces.